# How can I access a signer certificate from a java app in Websphere in order to load TrustMaterial into an SSLContext?

Tags: certificate, websphere, httpclient, truststore, sslcontext

I want to create an HttpClient with a TrustStore that includes our signer certificate from the WebSphere NodeDefaultTrustStore.

To do that have to either:

- get the certificate and create a TrustStore to load into a custom SSLContext using the TLSv1.2 protocol
- get an SSLContext from WebSphere that already incorporates such a TrustStore and protocol.

I have not been able to find a way to achieve either.

I know the disk address of the certificate stored by WebSphere, but it is stored as a .p12 file, and if I create the SSLContext in java, I need a .jks file.

I can import the .cer file into a .jks file and load it from disk from within the java code, but we already have the certificate loaded in WebSphere and would prefer to use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if JSSEHelper.getSSLContext() works...

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ssl/JSSEHelper.html#getSSLContext(java.util.Map,%20java.util.Properties)